# Create BMP Screenshot and save as 8pp Grayscale

Tags: vb.net

I'm having a lot of problems trying to accomplish this task. I know how to create a screenshot and save it as a bitmap....

```
    Dim printscreen As New Bitmap(thewidth, theheight, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb)
    Dim xscreenshot As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(printscreen)
    Dim theTest As New Size(thewidth, theheight)

    Dim theXLoc As String = "200"
    Dim theYLoc As String = "200"

    xscreenshot.CopyFromScreen(theXLoc, theYLoc, 0, 0, theTest)

    printscreen.Save("C:\Temp\printscreen.bmp", ImageFormat.MemoryBmp)
```

However when you pull up the options for Pixelformat. there is no option to save in 8pp. I really am trying to do this because I have been using AFORGE.Imaging library for image comparisons and in order to compare grayscale images they have to be in 8pp format.

Comment: `PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed` is that not what you want?

Comment: That option throws an invalid format error when I try to use that option. Apparently that option isn't greyscale its 8bit color